# matplotlib, can plot but not scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have weird behaviour of matplotlib.pyplot. I have two array x and y. I want scatter these point. so I use scatter function:

```
ax.scatter(x, y, 'r')
plt.xlabel('average revsion size')
plt.ylabel('time (seconds)')
plt.savefig('time.png', format='png')
```

this piece of code give me error
`otImplementedError: Not implemented for this type`
But if I substitute plt.scatter by plt.plot, then it plots it. What is the problem could be.

Also If I use plt.show() it opens 25 window (25 is length of x). Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The thing is that `scatter` and `plot` don't take the arguments in the same order. Try using `scatter(x, y, c='r')` instead (assuming it was the coloring you intended to set). Take a look at the [documentation for `scatter`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) as well.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [2,4,6,3,1,5]

plt.scatter(x, y, c='r')
plt.show()
```